# What is .rds_delta file?

Tags: widget, gitignore, tizen

I see a file in the root folder of my Tizen project called .rds_delta that contains what appears to be change commands for something. A Google search reveals nothing. Does anyone know what this file is for and if it should be kept in the Git repository, or should we add this to .gitignore?

.rds_delta file:

```
#delete
#add
#modify
res/wgt/author-signature.xml
res/wgt/config.xml
res/wgt/signature1.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a file that inform application installer what is changed in your app between one package build and second one. This is needed to quick application install from SDK.

Some official link: https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/native-application/application-development-process/running-applications

In my opinion it shouldn't be throw into Git repository.